# TextView.setHeight(); issues

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to dynamically change the height of a `TextView` programmatically in Android/Java and I can seem to get it to work. I have tried invalidating the TV before hand with no luck. If I get the height after I have set it, it returns a value of `0` but still takes up the space on the layout set by the `layout_height` in the XML code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's some what confusing at first, but Views do not actually get defined a height until they are displayed and drawn on the screen. That's just how Android user interface works. Have you tried `textView.getLayoutParams().height = (value here)`?

Comment: I had not tried that but it works perfectly, thank you good sir

Comment: In case anybody needed If you are doing this in any loop then textview.requestLayout()  also helps!!